# Automated Action Grant Portal Access

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

Im trying to make an Automated Action, when I create a user also grand access to portal.

My code so far is bind on button `Apply to All` (see image below):

```
for rec in records:
  for user in rec.user_ids:
    user['in_portal'] = True
rec.action_apply()
```

`Apply to All` Button Code: `<button name="563" type="action" string="Apply to All"/>`

[image]

How can i modify the code so it run, when I create a user and also grand access to portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options, to implement what you need.

1. Override `create()` of model `res.users` and just add users to your desired group(s) after super call.
2. Create an automated action (Settings/Technical/Automation/Automated Actions)

   - Model: Users (res.users)
   - Trigger Condition: On Creation
   - Action To Do: Update the Record
   - Data to Write: add one line

     - Field: Groups (res.users)
     - Evaluation Type: Python expression
     - Value: [(4,env.ref('`external id of group`').id)]

       Substitute `external id of group` with `base.group_portal` so in your case it    should be `[(4,env.ref('base.group_portal').id)]`